# Is my bash file stupid, can it be simplified?

Tags: bash

I made a couple pipe menus for Openbox over the last couple of days, which was fun as I knew nothing about bash previously. One displayed the output of df but it seems a limit to menu width undermined this. This one, on the other hand, works like a dandy for me. I don't understand entirely how it works, so for the sake of my own bash/awk education, I ask you, can it be simplified without using bc or acpi or something else I might not have installed?

```
#!/bin/sh

now=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now`
full=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full`

Date=$(date '+%R %a %x')
Wifi=$(cat /proc/net/wireless | awk 'NR==3 {print $3}')
Batt=$(echo $now $full | awk '{ printf("%.2f\n", $1/$2 * 100) }')

echo "<openbox_pipe_menu>"

echo "<separator label=\"$Date\"/>"
echo "<separator />"
echo "<item label=\"Wifi:  $Wifi%\"/>"
echo "<item label=\"Batt: $Batt%\"/>"

echo "</openbox_pipe_menu>"
```

Comment: Replace usage of `\`\`` with `$()`. I'd add some basic error handling atleast. Also as someone mentioned, it's `#!/bin/bash` for `bash`. If you are gonna use `#!/bin/sh` then make sure the code is somewhat portable (most often means that you shouldn't use bash-stuff) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First if it's for bash, use the proper header:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

No need to use `cat`, just use `$(<)`:

```
now=$(</sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now)
full=$(</sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full)
```

No need to use cat again since awk can accept input or parse files by itself:

```
Wifi=$(awk 'NR==3 {print $3}' /proc/net/wireless)
```

Quote your variables between `""` properly:

```
Batt=$(echo "$now $full" | awk '{ printf("%.2f\n", $1/$2 * 100) }')
```

Basically that's all I can see that's apparent.

**UPDATE**

As suggested by user000001, you could also use here strings:

```
Batt=$(awk '{ printf("%.2f\n", $1/$2 * 100) }' <<< "$now $full")
```

Answer (score 2):

Here document, and use file arguments to `awk`:

```
#!/bin/bash
cat <<EOF
<openbox_pipe_menu>
<separator label="$(date '+%R %a %x')" />
<separator />
<item label="Wifi: $(awk 'NR==3 {print $3}' /proc/net/wireless)%" />
<item label="Batt: $(awk '{ printf("%.2f\n", $1/$2 * 100) }' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_{now,full})%"/>
</openbox_pipe_menu>
EOF
```

Comment: did it give you an error? If it gave you an error, it was probably because of the use of multiple files with `awk`. You can change the line to `$(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_{now,full} | awk '{ printf("%.2f\n", $1/$2 * 100) }')`.

Comment: It didn't really give me an error, it just didn't display any number in the menu, and the change didn't fix it. interesting

Comment: Putting the two files on the command line is not the same as echoing them in on one line.  They will appear as two separate lines, rather than two words on one line.  Thus, the $1 and $2 no longer work.

Comment: Before you use a Here Document approach, you should ask yourself whether it makes the code more clear - or less.  Shell scripts are just like other programs, they should be clear to read and well commented.  Cramming everything into one here doc is counter to that.

Comment: BTW: echo is built into bash (and most or all shells), whereas cat costs an execution.  So doing six echos is actually more efficient than doing one cat.

Answer (score 1):

Looks pretty good actually :)

There are some micro-optimisations that can be done.

```
Wifi=$(cat /proc/net/wireless | awk 'NR==3 {print $3}')
```

You can save a process and execution with:

```
Wifi=$(awk 'NR==3 {print $3}' < /proc/net/wireless)
```

And the now/full behaviour could be simplified down too.  But, honestly, sometimes these changes might make it less readable than it is now.  You can be pretty happy with what you've done.

Comment: this works with or without the < does it make any difference?

Comment: The `<` directs the file into the program's standard input (like cat + |).  If you omit it, awk will see the filename as a parameter instead and read the named file.  So in this case, functionally they are the same.  Either way is "right" :)  You could make arguments either way for which is best.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of saying:

```
now=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now`
full=`cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full`

Batt=$(echo $now $full | awk '{ printf("%.2f\n", $1/$2 * 100) }')
```

say:

```
Batt=$(awk '{ printf("%.2f\n", $1/$2 * 100) }' /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full)
```

**EDIT:**

It seems that the input files to `Batt` contain a number each that needs to be divided.  You can say:

```
Batt=$(echo "scale=2; 100 *" $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_now) / $(cat /sys/class/power_supply/BAT0/charge_full) | bc -l)
```

to achieve the desired result.

Comment: Putting the two files on the command line is not the same as echoing them in on one line. They will appear (to awk) as two separate lines, rather than two words on one line. Thus, the $1 and $2 no longer work.

Comment: I didn't realize that those files contained nothing much a number each that needed to be divided.  See edit above.